# How make a dynamic background div in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background

I created the following image below just to help you guys understand what I'm trying to do here.
[image: background]

I need to have this divisions in my web page but I don't know how I could do there in a dynamic way.
I have contents that is gonna be dynamic, for example, sometimes I have a small text, but sometimes I have a bigger text and the page don't follow the same structure as when it was in a small text content.

- [Here is a page with a **small** text](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5714646/BrainSet/Website/site/index-1.html).
- [Here is a page with a **big** text](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5714646/BrainSet/Website/site/index-1_2.html).

I would like the background follow the size of the content and keep the same structure as I'm showing in the image above.

**UPDATE:**
Coco approach:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try like this layout. i think this will help you to correct this issue

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kAsCF/)

HTML :

```
<div class="outer-div">
         <div class="top-bg">
             <div class="container">
                 <p>sadasdasdasdsad</p>
                 <p>sadasdasdasdsad</p>
                 <p>sadasdasdasdsad</p>
                 <p>sadasdasdasdsad</p>
                 <p>sadasdasdasdsad</p>
             </div>
         </div>
        <div class="middle-bg">
            <div class="bg-bottom-div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.outer-div {
    background:#000;
}
.top-bg {
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
.container {
    background:#fff;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.middle-bg {
    background:#880015;
}
.bg-bottom-div {
    background:#fff;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}
.footer {
    background:#00a2e8;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks mate, not even the support of templatemonster.com could help me that, thanks, really, thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm missing something but it seems the only thing you need is this: where you have

```
.border-top {width:100%; background:url(../images/border-top-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;}
```

change it by

```
.border-top {width:100%; background:url(../images/border-top-tail.gif);}
```

and the background will cover the page as you need

Comment: I update my post, I try to do what you said, but it seems that don't stay in the structure that I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content for that particular background color/section in a div that is 100% of the width that you desire. Play around w/ the percentage widths for your desired fluid image:

```
#div_background_wrap1 { width:100%; background-color:#000;}
#div_background_wrap2 { width:75%; background:img url; margin:auto;}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="div_background_wrap1">
<div id="div_background_wrap2">
 <div>
 //content here//
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

And for resizing text, consider using CSS3 Media Queries

[CSS3 Media Queries](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/)

Comment: I will try your suggestion later mate, I have to go to the college now, =]

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand- maybe working with Sanooj's code w/ fixed widths would be easier. Play around with negative top margins to correctly position your divs.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if I understood well, but I think you would have to add

`background-position: bottom`